# How to export image/imagecollection (raster) as table in GEE?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, export, table, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have calculated LST (land surface temperature) of a city, so I have an image. I can export it to my drive as .tiff, but what I need is a table that contain LST value for each longitude and latitude in that city.
I don't know how to export that image to a table (or something like that which contain value of LST in specific long/lat).
How to do this task using Javascript GEE?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ee.Image.sample`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.sample). It creates features out of pixels of an image.

```
var table = image.sample({
  region: myRegion,  // myRegion should be a geometry, the bounds of the city
  scale: 50,  // how far apart in meters the samples are (approximately; depends on projection)
  geometries: true,  // include the sampled points in export
});
Export.table.toDrive(table);
```